# Where should I put index.jsp file?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

Where do I need to put `index.jsp` file ?

[image]

I put it inside the `war` directory but it gives `404 error` after I deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the /war directory. Check that you included the following lines in the web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: It is there.But i am still getting the 404 error and I have placed the index.jsp as http://i60.tinypic.com/2hf0tbn.png

Comment: Can you access it on the localhost? Are you using http or https?

Comment: I get this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/agent/AppEngineDevAgent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` as I try to run it on the localhost

Comment: Remove period from your version number. Make it 51-0, for example.

Comment: Where do I find it ? `appengine-web.xml` lists the version as  `1`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0